# Calculate the difficulty of a Code Golf question

Tags: code-golf, math

## Briefing

The difficulty of a Code Golf question can be calculated as such:

$$\text{clamp} \left( \left\lceil \left( \frac v a \div 700 \right) \times 10 \right\rceil, 0, 10 \right)$$

Where \$v\$ is the number of views a question has

and \$a\$ is the number of answers a question has

and \$⌈x⌉\$ is the [ceiling operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Also:

$$\text{clamp}(x, min, max) = \begin{cases}
min & x < min \\
x   & min \le x \le max \\
max & max < x
\end{cases}$$

This question's current difficulty: `***`

## Task

Write a program that will take two integers `(v and a)` and output the difficulty in `asterisks (*)`.

The input can be in the form of an array, a separated string or as separate function arguments

## Test Data

```
Views   Answers Difficulty  Program Output
163     2       2           **
548     22      1           *
1452    24      1           *
1713    37      1           *
4162    32      2           **
3067    15      3           ***
22421   19      10          **********
```

#### Example with pseudocode

```
v: 1713    
a: 37
out = clamp(ceil(((v/a)/700)*10), 0, 10); // evaluates to 1
//program will output '*'
```

The shortest code in bytes wins! Trailing/ leading spaces are allowed.

Comment: @SeanBean Trailing spaces allowed?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes.

Comment: I find that LaTeX harder to understand that a simple formula string.. but whatever the majority wants I guess..

Comment: Will `v` or `a` ever be negative?

Comment: You should almost add [[tag:underhanded]] for the **question** being underhanded.

Comment: Given the current formula, unanswered questions will always have a difficulty score of 10 (assuming the convention that dividing a positive number by zero gives positive infinity). This feels unfair to me.

Comment: This is a Code Golf question. Not an actual system being implemented into the site. Who cares if it's unfair?

Comment: Also I don't know if all the answers below actually work with 0 questions.

Comment: its kinda early so I may be missing something here, but why `/700 * 10` instead of `/70`?

Comment: @KevinL Ssshhhh ;)

Comment: @Adám Tag wiki for [tag:underhanded]: `This tag exists for historical reasons. New questions of the type previously posted under this tag are not welcome.`

Comment: What should occur when `views` and/or `answers` ==0? (granted, views==0 implies answers==0, but hey).

Comment: It doesn't matter really.

Comment: @Peanut I know, but here the OP isn't calling for underhanded answers, it is the *OP's challenge* which is underhanded: SeanBean incredibly manages to fool most (all?) the experienced golfers into writing unnecessarily *long* code!

Comment: You should add a test case where **v/a** is evenly divisible by **70**, e.g., **70, 1, 1**.

Comment: I was really hoping that this would be a competition for writing code that tries to predict some measure of difficulty based on the text of the question.

Comment: @MarkS. I'll try and think of a question based around that idea if you like? Or you can do it yourself :P

Comment: How do you build a code to test how hard *this* question is?...

Comment: @DonielF I just edit the question everynow and again, running it through my version of the program.

Comment: @Sean That was a failed joke. Apparently you missed the humor in it. Oh well.

Comment: @DonielF Care to explain?

Comment: Will **v** or **a** ever be zero? What should the outputs be in those cases?

Answer (score 49):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
v=>a=>"**********".substring(10-v/a/70)
```

Because `substring` provides the required clamping and "ceil"ing behaviour. Edit: Normally I'm too lazy to bother, but because it got 4 upvotes, I've followed @MarsUltor's advice to save 1 byte by currying.

Comment: Oh, that is a nice use of substring :-)

Comment: Use currying: `v=>a=>`

Comment: Can you use `substr` instead? I know the second parameter makes a difference, but not sure about the first...

Comment: @DomHastings: Yes, though `slice` would be even shorter.

Comment: @DomHastings No, both `substr` and `slice` interpret a negative argument as counting back from the end of the string.

Comment: Ah of course, I forget they're so different, always assume they're pretty much synonyms. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice it could be negative.

Comment: Got it! 37 bytes: `v=>a=>"**********".slice(0,v/a/70+.5)`

Comment: @Yay295 I don't think that works for `v=71, a=1`.

Comment: Dangit, you're right. `v=>a=>"**********".slice(0,v/a/70-.5|0+1)` fixes that, but it's 41 bytes.

Comment: This answer has got four(ty two) upvotes. So you were right to use currying.

Answer (score 38):

I've been wanting to do this for a while...

### HTML + CSS <s>491</s> <s>487</s> 485 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Conor O'Brien*
*-2 bytes thanks to Releasing Helium Nuclei*

Input is taken as the width and height of the page window; width being the number of Views, and height being the number of Answers.

```
<style>p{overflow:hidden;width:1ch}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/2){p{width:1ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/3){p{width:2ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/4){p{width:3ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/5){p{width:4ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/6){p{width:5ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/7){p{width:6ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/8){p{width:7ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/9){p{width:8ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:7/1){p{width:9ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/11){p{width:10ch</style><p>**********
```

You can try it in your browser by entering

```
data:text/html,<style>p{overflow:hidden;width:1ch}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/2){p{width:1ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/3){p{width:2ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/4){p{width:3ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/5){p{width:4ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/6){p{width:5ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/7){p{width:6ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/8){p{width:7ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/9){p{width:8ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:7/1){p{width:9ch}}@media(max-aspect-ratio:70/11){p{width:10ch</style><p>**********
```

as a url in a new tab.

Comment: +1 for thinking out of the box – ehm, thinking of the box...

Comment: Do you need the closing p tag?

Comment: I love how it updates as I change the window's size.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: Good point!

Comment: You don't need the last two `}`s too.

Answer (score 12):

### 05AB1E, 11 bytes

```
/70/î'*T×s£
```

**Explanation**

```
/            # divide v by a
 70/         # divide by 70
    î        # round up, call this n
     '*T×    # push 10 asterisks
         s£  # take n up to 10 asterisk
             # implicitly print
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LzcwL8OuJypUw5dzwqM&input=MTUKMzA2Nw)

Answer (score 12):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
v=>a=>"*".repeat((v/=a*70)<9?v+1:10)
```

*Saved 1 byte by currying, thanks to TheLethalCoder*

```js
let F=
v=>a=>"*".repeat((v/=a*70)<9?v+1:10)

console.log("Test #1:", F(163)(2))    // **
console.log("Test #2:", F(548)(22))   // *
console.log("Test #3:", F(1452)(24))  // *
console.log("Test #4:", F(1713)(37))  // *
console.log("Test #5:", F(4162)(32))  // **
console.log("Test #6:", F(3067)(15))  // ***
console.log("Test #7:", F(22421)(19)) // **********
```

Comment: Can you use `v=>a=>` instead of `(v,a)=>`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - Updated. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for `v=70, a=1` does it?

Comment: @Neil - That's right. It is off by 1 point if the number of answers is an exact divisor of the number of views. Or put in other words, it's anticipating the next view. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, <s>38</s> 35 bytes

```
StringRepeat["*",10,⌈#/#2/70⌉]&
```

*Thanks to @MartinEnder for 3 bytes*

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is a great answer!

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Thanks! Originally I was thinking of `Clip`, which has pretty much the same syntax as OP's Clamp, but then I saw that `StringRepeat` has the optional third argument for truncation.

Comment: There are Unicode characters for the left and right ceiling bracket which together make up only 6 bytes instead of the 9 you need for `Ceiling[]`.

Answer (score 9):

### EXCEL, 29 bytes

If you count Excel as a representation of VBA Excel, then you can use

```
=REPT("*",MIN(1+v/(70*a),10))
```

where `v` and `a` are the name of reference cells.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! This is a nice first post! And valid also.

Comment: Hi too @EasterlyIrk. Thanks for the warm welcome :)

Answer (score 8):

### CJam, <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Peter Taylor and 3 bytes thanks to Adnan*

```
'*A*q~d/70/m]<
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='*A*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Push%20%22**********%22%0A%20%20%20%20q~d%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Get%20the%20input%20and%20divide%20the%20two%20numbers%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2070%2F%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Divide%20by%2070%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20m%5D%20%20%20e%23%20Ceil%2C%20yielding%20x%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20%20e%23%20Slice%20the%20string%2C%20taking%20the%20first%20x%20elements&input=1452%2024)

```
'*A*            e# Push "**********"
    q~d/        e# Get the input and divide the two numbers
        70/     e# Divide by 70
           m]   e# Ceil, yielding x
             <  e# Slice the string, taking the first x elements
```

Answer (score 7):

### C#, <s>68</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
v=>a=>"**********".Substring((int)(10-v/a/70d));
```

This is the C# version of [this excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90138/38550) by Neil.

*Saved another 19 bytes thanks to Neil*

Comment: Try `(int)System.Math.Floor(10-v/a/70)` or just `(int)(10-v/a/70)`.

Comment: @Neil Looks like I had to leave the `70d` alone but works better thanks

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the `d` there.

Comment: Another answer that could save one byte with currying, I think: `v=>a=>`

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Didn't even realise how I could do it in C# thanks

Comment: If C# rounding is the same as Java, then when you cast to an integer, it rounds the double, it doesn't use the ceiling operator.

Comment: @Advancid Neither language rounds, as far as I know. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @Neil Sorry I meant remove decimals instead of round.

Comment: @Advancid That's why you subtract it from 10 first. `10-ceil(x) == floor(10-x)`.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, 57 bytes

Uses a lambda to save bytes, performs the calculation and substrings to return the answer.

```java
(v,a)->"**********".substring(Math.max(0,(700*a-v)/70/a))
```

---

Here is my class for testing it.

```java
public class DifficultyCalculator{
    static interface h{ String f(int v, int a);}
    static void g(h H){
        System.out.print(H.f(163,2));System.out.println("\t**");
        System.out.print(H.f(548,22));System.out.println("\t*");
        System.out.print(H.f(1452,24));System.out.println("\t*");
        System.out.print(H.f(1713,37));System.out.println("\t*");
        System.out.print(H.f(4162,32));System.out.println("\t**");
        System.out.print(H.f(3067,15));System.out.println("\t***");
        System.out.print(H.f(22421,19));System.out.println("\t**********");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        g( // 70
            (v,a)->"**********".substring(java.lang.Math.max(0,(int)(10-v/70d/a)))
        );
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

- **-3** [16-08-19] Utilized integer division
- **-10** [16-08-18] Removed unnecessary import, thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*!
- **-18** [16-08-17] Return string instead of print

Comment: Nice, a Java answer that isn't a train!

Comment: No need for `java.lang.` since it's the default included package.

Comment: You are rounding not ceiling!

Comment: @Advancid I tested it and `System.out.println((int)2.99);` prints `2` and since I take the pre-floored value from 10 and then floor it, it is the same as taking the ceiling away from 10.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
/70/0:9>42*c
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=LzcwLzA6OT40Mipj&input=MzA2NwoxNQ)

#### Explanation

The rounding up and clamping are done simultaneously as follows: the number `x = v/a/70` is compared against each element of the array `[0 1 ... 9]`. The numbers of that array that are exceeded by `x` will become asterisks, and the rest will be spaces.

```
/      % Take the two numbers implicitly. Divide. (Example: for inputs 3067, 15
       % we get 204.47)
70/    % Divide by 70 (we get 2.92)
0:9    % Push array [0 1  ... 9]
>      % See which of those are exceeded by the previous number (2.92 exceeds
       % 0, 1 and 2, so we get [1 1 1 0 ... 0]). This does the rounding up
       % and the clamping
42*    % Multiply by 42, which is the ASCII code of '*' (we get [42 42 42 0 ... 0])
       % Char 0 will be displayed as space
c      % Convert to char. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python2, 32 bytes

saved 3 + 2 bytes and corrected off by one error thanks to Leaky Nun

```
lambda v,a:('*'*10)[:~-v/a/70+1]
```

similar to Neils answer. Uses the fact that Python2 does integer division.

Comment: fails when `v=70` and `a=1`

Comment: The `f=` can be removed

Comment: `v, a` can become `v,a`

Comment: thanks! should work now. May be wrong for v=0, a=1 now, but this case cannot exist, can it?

Comment: That would not be wrong for v=0, a=1.

Comment: Instead of using `(v-1)`, you can use `~-v`.

Comment: thanks - no idea how that works

Comment: `~` is bitwise negation, which turns `n` to `-(n+1)`. ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for more info)

Comment: Why *10 then substring? Multiply with the right amount straight away: `lambda v,a:('*'*(~-v/a/70+1))`

Comment: @KarlNapf beucase `~-v/a/70+1` may generate a number higher than 10 (last test for example)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 35 bytes

```
v#a=[1..min(ceiling$v/a/70)10]>>"*"
```

`[1..min(ceiling$v/a/70)10]` creates a range from 1 to the computed difficulty (an empty list for difficulty 0). `a>>b` repeats the list `b` `length a` often.

Answer (score 4):

### C#, <s>97</s> <s>89</s> <s>87</s> <s>77</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
v=>a=>new string('*',(v/=a*70)<9?v+1:10);
```

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to Adám*

*Saved a few bytes thanks to Arnauld*

Comment: You can save a whole lot by replacing `(int)System.Math.Ceiling(v/a/70d)` by `(v+69)/(70*a)`... Note that moreover v/a can not be negative, so `c` can be simplified a lot because you don't need to check for that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>17</s> 13 bytes

**4 bytes in credit to Luis Mendo for [his algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90141/48934).**

```
*\*htS[0T.EccFQ70
*\*s>LccFQ70T
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a%5C%2as%3ELccFQ70T&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=163%2C2%0A548%2C22%0A1452%2C24%0A1713%2C37%0A4162%2C32%0A3067%2C15%0A22421%2C19&debug=0)

Comment: [Also 13 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30YrRkvPNdlNO9DcIOT/f2MDM3MdBUNTAA)

Answer (score 4):

## R,  <strike>68, 50</strike> 52  bytes

```
f=function(v,a)cat(rep("*",1+min(v/a/70,10)),sep="")
```

`rep` implicitly places a min on number of 0.

Thanks to @plannapus and @Anastasiya-Romanova秀  for spotting my error.

Comment: You can remove `f=`

Comment: Outputs of your code are not equal to the Test Data. You should add 2 more bytes `1+` after `min(` in order to get the same outputs

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```
say"*"x(10-($-=10-pop()/70/pop))
```

Use `-E` to activate `say` and give the arguments in the reverse order:

```
perl -E 'say"*"x(10-($-=10-pop()/70/pop))' 2 163
```

If arguments on STDIN are allowed the following is 29 bytes:

```
(echo 163; echo 2) | perl -pe '$_="*"x(10-($-=10-$_/70/<>))'
```

Comment: I can't remember if it'd exactly the same, but can you have `0|` instead of `$-=`? (Thinking operator precedence might not be right...)

Comment: @DomHastings `0|` makes a negative number into a huge number (leading to zero `*`s), `$-=` clips to 0 (leading to ten `*`s), which is what I need here

Comment: Ah, of course, it's only ever a positive integer! Thanks for reminding. I'm sure I'll forget that when I need it though... 

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, <s>13</s> 9 bytes

```
/70/\**T<
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2F70%2F%5C%2a%2aT%3C&input=2%0A163&warnings=0)

Explanation:

```
/         -    num_1 / num_2
 70/      -   ^ / 70
    \**   -  "*" * ^
       T< - ^[:10]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 48 bytes

```
a=>b=>"*".repeat(Math.ceil(Math.min(a/b/70,10)))
```

Answer (score 3):

## m4, <s>136</s> 135 bytes

```
define(r,`ifelse($1,0,,eval($1>9),1,*`r(9)',*`r(decr($1))')')define(f,`r(ifelse(eval($1%($2*70)),0,eval($1/$2/70),eval($1/$2/70+1)))')
```

Defines a macro `f` which takes `v` and `a`, and expands to the correct output. Most of the program is an implementation of ceiling.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>54</s>, <s>51</s>, <s>50</s>, 49 bytes

Assuming that `v` is positive or zero and `a` positive, the `x < min` clamping case is never met, since there is no way the result of the ceiling operation can be negative. Additionally, integer maths on non-negative values always yields the floor of the result, so we add `1` to get the ceiling.

This solution requires a `write` function, works on Linux at least.

```
F(v,a){write(1,"**********",(v/=a*70)>9?10:v+1);}
```

Test main:

```
int main() {
  F(163, 2);
  putchar('\n');
  F(548, 22);
  putchar('\n');
  F(1452, 24);
  putchar('\n');
  F(1713, 37);
  putchar('\n');
  F(4162, 32);
  putchar('\n');
  F(3067, 15);
  putchar('\n');
  F(22421, 19);
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Replacing `(v=v/a/70)` with `(v/=a*70)` saves 1 byte.

Comment: Nice catch @ceilingcat!

Answer (score 2):

### javascript: <s>82</s> 73 bytes

```
 (v,a)=>console.log("*".repeat(Math.min(Math.max(0,Math.ceil(v/a/70),10)))
```

- *saved some bytes after Adám pointed out I overlooked the /700*10=/70*, and the removal of parens

Comment: @Adám what's with the edit?

Comment: @Adám If people read any of the answers they'll have the spoiler already. Rolling back, because currently that sentence is fairly useless and just makes people click on the revision history.

Comment: @Adám That's what I usually use myself but I don't see any harm in the current version.

Comment: No need to `console.log` it, returning is fine. You can also save a byte with `v=>a=>` instead of `(v,a)=>`

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 15 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
'*'⍴⍨10⌊⌈⎕÷70×⎕
```

`'*'⍴⍨` the character repeated this many times:
`10⌊` min(10,...
`⎕÷` input divided by
`70×` seventy times
`⎕` input

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2191%u2191%7B%27*%27%u2374%u23680%u230810%u230A%u2308%u237A%F770%D7%u2375%7D/%A8%28163%202%29%28548%2022%29%281452%2024%29%281713%2037%29%284162%2032%29%283067%2015%29%2822421%2019%29&run)

Comment: Would it be golfier to use Mendo's algorithm?

Comment: @LeakyNun I don't think so: `'*'/⍨(⎕÷70×⎕)>⍳10`

Answer (score 2):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 18 bytes

```
P
#'*
mM/%i
10 %70
```

Takes input in the format `[a v]`. [Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=UAojJyoKbU0vJWkKMTAgJTcw&input=WzIgMTYzXQ)

### Explanation

- `%` is reciprocal, so `%70` is 1/70.
- `i` is input, as a two-element array.
- `/%` with inputs `i` and `%70` reduces the array `i` by flipped division with initial value `%70`. In other words, it computes **v/(a/(1/70))**, which is equal to **v / (70*a)**.
- `M` takes the ceiling of this value, and `m` takes the maximum of that and `10`.
- `#'*` repeats the literal `*` character that many times.
- `P` prints the result without quotes.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <strike>34</strike> 33 bytes

Because I like this challange so much, here is one for MATLAB (outputs trailing whitespaces):

```
@(v,a)[(ceil(v/a/70)>0:9)*42,'']
```

Inspired by @Luis Mendo's answer. Thanks to @pajonk for saving one byte.

Comment: Nice approach! I had a 40-byte one to post... BTW, you can save one byte using `[... '']` instead of `char(...)`. And do you really need the `ceil` when at the end you are comparing with integers?

Comment: thanks @pajonk - one can really learn some things on this site to make my code even less readable ;)

Answer (score 2):

## dc, <s>110 108 104</s> 98 bytes

This was a doozy since slicing isn't a thing. Also, dc doesn't manipulate strings. I just really was waiting for a string one that would be < 5 hours of coding. On the plus side, I finally started writing down common constructs, like for loops. Also had to formulate rounding/ceiling, so thanks for that.

```
[42P]sd[dsi[li0!=dli1-dsi0!=L]dsLx]sl[Isi[li0!=dli1-dsi0!=L]dsLx]sg[1+]saIk/70*0k1~0!=adI>ldI!>gIP
```

Invoked in bash:

```
echo 'v a (above)'|dc
# Wholly:
>> echo '163 2 [42P]sd[dsi[li0!=dli1-dsi0!=L]dsLx]sl[Isi[li0!=dli1-dsi0!=L]dsLx]sg[1+]saIk/70*0k1~0!=adI>ldI!>gIP'|dc
# outputs:
**
>>
```

Replacing (above) with the code, and `v` and `a` with their respective counterparts above. The single quotes are important (otherwise you get bash's history stuff).

---

Explained:

```
[42P]sd   # Here we store a macro in register d to print 1 * without a newline

[dsi[li0!=dli1-dsi0!=L]dsLx]sl # Store the "less than" case, a for loop which
                        # uses the top-of the stack as it's number of iterations.
[Isi[li0!=dli1-dsi0!=L]dsLx]sg # Store the "greater than" case. It's the above,
                        # but it puts 10 on the stack to use instead.

[1+]sa # Store a macro to add 1 to whatever is the top-of-stack.


Ik # Set precision at non-zero to allow decimal division

/70* # Divide the top two of the stack, v/a; multiply by 70 (`/700*10` == `/70`)
             # dc is postfix and stack-based, so operators come after operands.

0k1~0!=a     # This is a ceiling function.
|> 0k  # set precision to 0 to perform integer division
|> 1~  # push the quotient of integer division by 1, and then the remainder. (r is top)
|> 0!=a # If the top-of-stack (decimal part) is not 0, add 1 to the quotient

dI>ldI!>g # Conditional statement
|> dI>l  # (d)uplicate the top, push 10 on. If 10 > the old top, execute the `l`ess-than
          # case, which loops top-of-stack times.
|> dI!>g # Complement of the above, using the `g`reater-than to loop 10 times.

IP # print a newline
```

This is probably more golf-able, but I was trying to get it finished to avoid premature optimization.

- 2 bytes saved by duplicating-saving instead of saving-loading
- 4 bytes saved dividing by 70
- 6 bytes from daniero's suggestions (non-strings, ASCII nums instead; 10 => I)

Comment: `[*]n` => `42P`. Every instance of `10` can be replaced by `I`. `[]p` => `IP`

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 35 bytes

This solution is as completely different from *Laikoni*s answer as it gets for something this trivial. Yet the score (for now) is exactly the same.

```haskell
v%a=take(ceiling$v/a/70)[0..9]>>"*"
```

This produces ten stars, then shaves off some. Easy to extend to arbitrary difficulty with an infinite list.

I did manage to shave off one more byte. But while all test cases work, this shouldn't be correct in general.

```haskell
v%a=take(1+div v(a*70))[0..9]>>"*"
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 39 bytes

```
Prompt V,A
sub("**********",1,max(0,min(10,int(V/A/70)+1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
/70/ṙ›\**
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2F70%2F%E1%B9%99%E2%80%BA%5C**&inputs=1%0A306&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 47 bytes

```
-join(('*'*11)[1..($args[0]/$args[1]/70+.499)])
```

Somewhat a port of @Neil's [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90138/42963).

Takes input `$args` and divides them, then divides that by `70`, and adds `.499`. Since PowerShell does [banker's rounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx#Midpoint), this is effectively `ceil` to two decimal points of precision. If additional precision is required, tack on as many additional `9`s as required.

Along with the `1..`, this forms a range index into a string. The string is `'*'*11`, i.e. `'***********'`. That results in a char-array, so we `-join` it together back into a string. That string is left on the pipeline and output is implicit. Like Neil's answer, this effectively "clamps" the output to be between 1 and 10 stars.

#### Test Suite

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> @(@(163,2), @(548,22), @(1452,24), @(1713,37), @(4162,32), @(3067,15), @(22421,19))|%{($_-join', ')+" -> " +(.\difficulty-of-a-question $_[0] $_[1])}
163, 2 -> **
548, 22 -> *
1452, 24 -> *
1713, 37 -> *
4162, 32 -> **
3067, 15 -> ***
22421, 19 -> **********
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>69</s> 68 bytes

I didn't want to copy the Python 2 answer, so mine is slightly longer.

```
from math import*
x=lambda v,a:print(max(0,min(ceil(v/a/70),10))*'*')
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to Program man

Comment: You do need to include imports, but `from math import *` will save a couple bytes

Comment: Included the import into the byte count

Comment: According to the spec, 0 is the minimum stars, not 1. Also save a whole 1 byte by `import*` with no space.

Comment: Oops I misread the minimum.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Programman Though the spec says 0 is minimum, division and multiplication of non-negative, non-zero integers is guaranteed to != 0, and the ceiling operator will make *anything* between 0-1 and make it 1. Although I suppose there could be the case of 0 views, however 0 views implies 0 answers, which leads to undefined behavior (division by 0). It's likely provable that 0 is impossible and should not even be mentioned.

Comment: @Delioth I did not consider that 0 views implies 0 answers, so you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, 46 bytes

All division in Fourier is integer division, so I just add one after division.

```
I*10/I/700^~X<0{1}{0~X}X>10{1}{10~X}X(42ai^~i)
```

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=SSoxMC9JLzcwMF5-WDwwezF9ezB-WH1YPjEwezF9ezEwflh9WCg0MmFpXn5pKQ&input=MzA2NwoxNQ)

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 14 bytes

```
:70a\\u9ukm'**
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OjcwYVxcdTl1a20nKio&input=MTYzCjI)

Takes advantage of the fact that 0 views and 0 answers is impossible, and thus `ceil(v/a) > 0`.

Explanation:

```
:70a\\u9ukm'**
:70             push 70 ([70 a v])
   a            invert stack ([v a 70])
    \\          integer division twice ([v//a//70])
      u         add 1 ([v//a//70 + 1])
       9uk      push 10, make stack into list ([[v//a//70+1, 10]])
          m     minimum of list
           '**  push "*", repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5.6, 66 bytes

```php
function a($v,$a){echo str_repeat('*',max(0,min(10,1+$v/$a/70)));}
```

First we simplify the equation to `v/a/70`. From there we add 1 since PHP will use this number as an integer for the `str_repeat`, essentially doing `abs($number+1)`. Then we use the hand-rolled `clamp` function of `max($min_number, min($max_number, $the_number))` to keep it between 1 and 10.

The `substr` version is a few bytes shorter (due to not having to have to build in the clamp functionality), but this one was more fun to make.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <strike>47</strike> 35 bytes

```
f=->(v,a){'*'*((v/=a*70)<9?v+1:10)}
```

Called with `f.call(v,a)`

Saved 12 bytes thanks to user3334690, now the function implicitly returns the result.

Comment: you can probably save a bit by doing string * number like: "q=->(v,a){'*'*((v/=a*70)<9?v+1:10)}"

Comment: You can safely remove `f=`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```
->v,a{(?**10)[1..(v/a/70)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6: 32 bytes

As a lambda that takes two arguments:

```
{"*"x min 10,ceiling $^x/$^y/70}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 17 bytes

```
L^,/70/i9b<"*"$yp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxNCoAgEEDhvaeIaBVBzo@aEHOCoBsEipugwG2nt3Yx2w/eS6XU2tp2THOw8xnz2o/98NQ2XOnOJXUg4EnQ7OYXx4ugJmCHgqwtAAkFZQwehXRL1gcBpwyR8TtEs7cX)

Not often I get to use the `^` flag in [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### How it works

```
L^,		; Create a lambda that returns the stack joined
		; Example arguments:	[3067 15]
	/	; Divide;		[204.46]
	70/	; Divide by 70;		[2.921]
	i	; Floor;		[2]
	9b>	; Minimum with 9;	[2]
	"*"	; Push '*';		[2 '*']
	y	; Repeat with an extra;	['*' '*' '*']
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
÷÷70Ċ«⁵”*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9sPbzQ2OdB1a/ahx66OGuVoV/w8vV4r8/9/QzFhHwdTEQkfB0MTUCEiaGwIFTAzNgGxjAzNzHQUjIxMjQx0FMwML0/9GIC4QmwAlgVLGIA2mQGwJ1GIAAA)

### How it works

```
÷÷70Ċ«⁵”*x - Main link. Takes v on the left and a on the right
÷          - v ÷ a
 ÷70       - v ÷ a ÷ 70
    Ċ      - ⌈v ÷ a ÷ 70⌉
     «⁵    - min(⌈v ÷ a ÷ 70⌉, 10)
       ”*x - Repeat "*" min(⌈v ÷ a ÷ 70⌉, 10) times
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 81 bytes

```
@set/an=(700*%2-%1)/%2/70,n*=!(n^>^>31)
@set s=**********
@call echo %%s:~%n%%%
```

Port of my JavaScript answer, except that Batch uses integer arithmetic, so I wrote the formula as `(700*a-v)/a/70` which will truncate towards zero, and then the `n*=!(n^>^>31)` clears `n` if it is negative.

Comment: Batch makes my eyes bleed, but nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
/70/ṃ'*T×ɱ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSUyRjcwJTJGJUUxJUI5JTgzJypUJUMzJTk3JUM5JUIxJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTUlMEEzMDY3JmZsYWdzPWU=)

##### Explanation

```python
/70/ṃ'*T×ɱ  '# Implicit input
/            # Divide v by a
 70/         # Divide this by 70
    ṃ        # Take the ceiling
     '*T×   '# Push 10 asterisks
         ɱ   # Take that many characters
             # (with a maximum of 10)
             # from the string
             # Implicit output
```