# North by North by North by South East

Tags: code-golf

Given a string of N, S, E and W, output a bearing (angle clockwise from North in degrees), correct to 5 decimal places.

In [traditional compass notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass#16-wind_compass_rose), a string is made up of only 2 of these characters (like NNW or ESE). **Here you must also accept strings that contain all 4 (like WNNNSE)**. Using only 2 symbols allows humans to intuitively understand the meaning. Allowing 4 symbols makes it horrible to read, but allows shorter ways of describing a bearing to a given accuracy.

*(As pointed out in the [comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99906/north-by-north-by-north-by-south-east?noredirect=1#comment242720_99906) by [user2357112](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12647/user2357112), it turns out you can prove that for any given bearing, the 4 symbol string will be exactly the same length as the 2 symbol string, so I've based this challenge on a false assumption. Hopefully this lack of a practical purpose doesn't detract from your enjoyment of the challenge...)*

The exact method is described below, and is equivalent to the traditional notation (it expands on it rather than changing it).

## Input

- The input is a single string containing only the characters `NESW`.
- The input may be a sequence of characters if you prefer, provided this does not include any preprocessing. For example, taking a nested list `[N, [E, [S, [W]]]]` to help with the order of processing is not permitted.
- Taking different characters is not permitted. You may not take a string of `1234` instead of `NESW`.

## Output

- The output must be a decimal number or string representation of one (not a rational/fraction).
- Trailing zeros do not need to be displayed. If the bearing is `9.00000`, then the output `9` also counts as correct to 5 decimal places.
- The output is in the range [0, 360). That is, including 0 but excluding 360.
- Correctness is checked by rounding the output to 5 decimal places. If the bearing is 0.000005, this rounds to 0.00001. Outputs 0.00001 and 0.000005 are both correct.
- Output in scientific notation for some inputs is acceptable. For example, `1e-5` instead of `0.00001`.

## Conversion

- The single character compass points `N`, `E`, `S`, and `W` correspond to 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees respectively.
- Prepending one of these to a string results in the bearing that bisects the bearing of the single character and the bearing of the original string.
- The closest of the two possible bisecting bearings is chosen, so that NE represents 45 degrees, not 225 degrees.
- This is unambiguous except where the angle to be bisected is 180 degrees. Therefore `NS`, `SN`, `WE`, and `EW` correspond to undefined bearings, and the input will never end in any of these. They may however appear anywhere else in the input string, as this causes no ambiguity.
- If the final two characters are identical, the final character will be redundant as the bisection will return the same bearing. Since this adds nothing to the notation, your code does not need to handle this. Therefore `NN`, `EE`, `SS`, and `WW` correspond to undefined bearings, and the input will never end in any of these. They may however appear anywhere else in the input string.

## Examples

```
N: 0
E: 90
S: 180
SE: halfway between S and E: 135
NSE: halfway between N and SE: 67.5
NNSE: halfway between N and NSE: 33.75
NNNSE: halfway between N and NNSE: 16.875
NNNNSE: halfway between N and NNNSE: 8.4375
```

## Test cases

A submission is only valid if it gives correct output for all of the test cases. Note that the test cases push to the limits of what can be handled with double precision. For languages that default to single precision, you will probably need to spend the bytes to specify double precision in order to get correct outputs.

Test case outputs are shown rounded to 5 decimal places, and also to arbitrary precision. Both are valid outputs.

```
WNE 337.5 337.5
WEN 337.5 337.5
WEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEN 330.00001 330.000007152557373046875
NESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESW 90 89.99999932944774627685546875
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE 0.00001 0.0000107288360595703125
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNW 359.99999 359.9999892711639404296875
SNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE 90.00001 90.00000536441802978515625
SNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNW 269.99999 269.99999463558197021484375
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The score is the length of the source code in bytes, and the shortest wins.

---

## <sup>Pedantry</sup>

> <sup>I made the mistake of thinking that "North by North West" was a valid compass direction. A happy mistake, since it led to a challenge idea, but I then discovered from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass#32-wind_compass_points):</sup>
>  <sup>*"The title of the Alfred Hitchcock 1959 movie, North by Northwest, is actually not a direction point on the 32-wind compass, but the film contains a reference to Northwest Airlines."*</sup>
>  <sup>It also turns out that the method used for this challenge is only consistent with traditional compass points up to and including the 16 point compass. The 32-wind compass described on that page is subtly different and I have conveniently overlooked its existence for this challenge.</sup>
>  <sup>Finally, for anyone who thinks I should use "Southeast" instead of "South East", it [seems to be a regional difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73712/is-there-some-difference-between-north-east-and-northeast).</sup>

Comment: `WNNNSE` <= what would be the output for this example entry at start of your post ? it sounds invalid for me, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Tensibai For input `WNNNSE` the output would be `323.4375`. See the example section for a walkthrough that would apply in the same way to this case.

Comment: Is input like `f(N,N,N,S,E)` okay?

Comment: @KarlNapf I've expanded the input section to clarify. If I understand correctly, your example input with multiple arguments seems equivalent to a sequence of characters, so it would be acceptable.

Comment: Is scientific notation accepted as output? For example, 1e-5 instead of 0.00001 when taking "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE" as input.

Comment: @Osable I've edited the output section to allow scientific notation.

Comment: As ever, I upvote for a good explanation.

Comment: @trichoplax *I made the mistake of thinking that "North by North West" was a valid compass direction* What? It *is* a valid compass direction. The Wikipedia page you linked to even says so. It's listed under "16-wind compass rose" as well as in the table of "32 cardinal points".

Comment: @mbomb007 I thought that section would clear up the pendantry :P Oh well, here goes: NNW (which I used to think was called "North by North West") is a point on the 16-wind compass, but it is called "North-Northwest". The names containing "by" are from the 32-wind compass, which puts the Northwest *first*, giving "Northwest by North". Note that NNW, called North-Northwest on the 16-wind compass, is a different direction than NWbN, called Northwest by North on the horribly confusing 32-wind compass (see 30 & 31 of 32). Hence my decision to quietly pretend the 32-wind compass never happened...

Comment: @trichoplax Same diff. As long as it's NNW, we know what you mean. Agreed. What 32-wind compass. That's what degrees are for.

Comment: [Related topic](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54755/convert-a-point-of-the-compass-to-degrees) but that one is a Kolmogorov complexity challenge.

Comment: "Allowing 4 symbols makes it horrible to read, but allows shorter ways of describing a bearing to a given accuracy." - are you sure about that? It seems like all inputs that describe the same bearing have the same length, since if you assign each bearing a dyadic rational from 0 to 1, a length-N string with N>1 always corresponds to a dyadic rational with denominator 2^(N+1) in lowest terms. Also, allowing more than 2 distinct letters in a bearing adds no expressive power; any bearing expressed with 3 or 4 letters can be expressed with 2.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for this insight! Yes, your explanation is correct (excluding precisely those strings excluded by the challenge). I thought that "to a given accuracy" would make a difference, since there will then be a range of different values that are close enough, but it turns out that even if you find the shortest string that gives a bearing that rounds to the desired accuracy, there is a string of that length containing only 2 symbols. So much for my plan for another challenge to find the shortest string - it becomes trivial with only 2 symbols...

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>84</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> <s>74</s> 72 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to @Titus, 1 thanks to @Neil*

```js
f=([c,...s],b="NESW".search(c))=>b*90-(s[0]?(b-=f(s)/90)-4*(b*b>4):0)*45
```

It took a while, but I think I've finally perfected the formula...

#### Test snippet

```js
f=([c,...s],b="NESW".search(c))=>b*90-(s[0]?(b-=f(s)/90)-4*(b*b>4):0)*45
g=(s,n)=>console.log('f("'+s+'"):',f(s),"expected:",n)

g("N", 0)
g("NE", 45)
g("E", 90)
g("SE", 135)
g("S", 180)
g("SW", 225)
g("W", 270)
g("NW", 315)
g("WNE", 337.5)
g("WEN", 337.5)
g("WEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEN", 330.00001)
g("NESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESW", 90)
g("NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE", 0.00001)
g("NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNW", 359.99999)
g("SNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE", 90.00001)
g("SNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNW", 269.99999)
```

#### Explanation

Let's start with the simplest case: a single-char string. The result is simply its (0-indexed) position in the string `NESW`, multiplied by 90.

For a two-char string, the result lies halfway between the result of the first char and the result of the second. However, there's a catch: if the absolute difference between the two is greater than 180 (e.g. `NW` or `WN`), we must 180 to the angle so that it's not pointing the opposite direction.

For any longer string, the result lies halfway between the result of the first char and the result of the rest of the string. This can be generalized in the following way:

- If the input is a single char, return its index in the string `NESW` times 90.
- Otherwise, return the index of the first char in the string `NESW` times 45, plus half the result of the rest of the string; add an extra 180 if the absolute difference between the two is greater than 90.

Comment: Excellent way to cutting the first character off the string! You can save one byte if you calculate with values divided by 45.

Comment: @Titus I can save 2 bytes with that technique, thanks!

Comment: `search` instead of `indexOf` to save you a byte.

Comment: @Neil Thanks again! I managed to golf off three more by completely rearranging the equation.

Answer (score 10):

### C#6, <s>226</s> <s>217</s> <s>207</s> 185 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;double N(string s){double b=f(s.Last());foreach(var c in s.Reverse()){b=(b+f(c)+(b-f(c)>2?4:f(c)-b>2?-4:0))/2;b=(b+4)%4;}return b*90;}int f(char x)=>"NESW".IndexOf(x);
```

Edit: -10 bytes by "borrowing" idea from ETHproductions's submission
-22 bytes thanks to @Titus

Ungolfed

```cs
// Call this method
double N(string s){
    // Initialize bearing with last direction
    double b=f(s.Last());
    // Do backward. Doing last direction once more doesn't impact result
    foreach(var c in s.Reverse()){
        // Average current bearing with new bearing, adjusted with wrapping
        b=(b+f(c)+(b-f(c)>2?4:f(c)-b>2?-4:0))/2;
        // Make bearing back to range [0,4)
        b=(b+4)%4;
    }
    // Change from "full circle = 4" unit to degree
    return b*90;
}
// helper method to convert direction to bearing. This returns bearing with full circle = 4.
int f(char x)=>"NESW".IndexOf(x);
```

Comment: I think you can make your range adjustment back to [0,360) shorter by using %

Comment: @trichoplax Won´t that cut the decimals?

Comment: @Titus [C# % works for floats as well as integers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).

Comment: Save 10 bytes with `b=(b+360)%360;` instead of `b+=b>360?-360:b<0?360:0;`. Save another 12 bytes with dividing everything by 90 and `return b*90;`.

Comment: Here are 10 more bytes: merge the two assignments and remove braces: `b=(b+f(c)+(b-f(c)>2?4:f(c)-b>2?-4:0)+8)/2%4;` then distribute `+8` to the ternary results `b=(b+f(c)+(b-f(c)>2?12:f(c)-b>2?4:8))/2%4;`

Comment: Convert your methods to `Func`s i.e. `Func<string, double>` and `Func<char, int>` saves around 28 bytes although I may have miscounted

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I think I tried `Func<char,int>` and it was worse. I can try `Func<string,double>` but I need to qualify it with `System.Func`. Will try

Comment: You do not need to include the `Func` in the byte count only `s=>....` see: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90139/38550, note that answer also makes use of currying

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, <s>95</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>100</s> <s>127</s> <s>104</s> 101 bytes

- -7 bytes with the null coalescing operator
- -2 bytes by not replacing `N` (and more, because that allows to put the translation to the loop head: `N` is truthy, but evaluates to `0` in the calculation.)
- +41 bytes for fixing the bisection (*cough*)
- -7 bytes directly and -16 indirectly inspired by @ETHproductions´ code
- -3 bytes by replacing `strtr` with one of my bit jugglings

---

```
for($i=strlen($s=$argv[1]);$i--;$p=($q+$p=$p??$q)/2+2*(abs($q-$p)>2))$q=ord($s[$i])/.8+3&3;echo$p*90;
```

This is officially the first time ever that I use the null coalescing operator. Run with `-r`.

### PHP 7.1

Negative string offsets in the upcoming PHP version will save 12 bytes:
Replace `strlen($s=$argv[1])` with `0` and `$s` with `$argv[1]`.

---

**Free bytes for (almost) everyone:**

- Calculating with 0,1,2,3 instead of 0,90,180,270 and multiplying the final result with 90 will save two bytes *and* probably allow further golfing.
- There are some patterns in the ASCII codes of the characters. Try one of these in your language:

  - `(a/2%6+2)%5`
  - `a<87?a/2&3^3:3` or `a/2&3^3*(a<87)`
  - `a&1?a&2|a/4&1:0`
  - `a/.8-1&3`

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>146</s> <s>145</s> <s>117</s> <s>107</s> <s>97</s> <s>94</s> <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```
f(s):u='NESW'.find(s[0])*90;return(u+f(s[1:]))/2+180*(abs(u-‌​f(s[1:]))>180)if s[1:]else u
```

Call `f` with the string.

Comment: You can't have the two `...0else` they throw SyntaxErrors.

Comment: @JonathanAllan What version of Python are you using? I'm on 3.5.2 and it works.

Comment: I ran it on 3.3.3 - can you remove the space between `else` and `-` too? (can in 3.3.3)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes I can! Thanks, that saves me another byte.

Comment: You can save 6 bytes with dividing everything by 90 and returning `90*b`; 3 more with `d='NESW'` and `d.find(...)`.

Comment: @Titus: Thanks! Plus another one by putting `d` inside the function.

Comment: Can assigning `d.find(c)` to a variable save anything? I guess not because that variable would have to be declared first.

Comment: @Titus `d.find` can, I had the exact idea a minute ago; see updated answer.

Comment: `f='NESW'.find` is very elegant. I was about to test this, thinking "but the parentheses are missing from find!", then I realised it makes a function which you reuse. Beautiful

Comment: @trichoplax I assume I can also ask the user for input and print the output? Then I could save another 3 bytes.

Comment: According to our defaults for input and output, [yes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2448/20283) and [yes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2450/20283). Go for it.

Comment: I'm getting 94 bytes for what you have so far, not 95. ( https://mothereff.in/byte-counter ) Also: you can save a byte by doing `s=input()[::-1]` (and just doing `for c in s:` in your loop), and initializing `b=f(s[0])`.

Comment: @mathmandan Good point about the `s=input()[::-1]`, but I get 94 bytes _with_ that improvement. Using `wc -c` to count. Edit: You're right, for some reason my file has a final newline.

Comment: OK, we can get to 92 by writing it as a recursive function: `def f(s):u='NESW'.find(s[0])*90;return(u+f(s[1:]))/2+180*(abs(u-f(s[1:]))>180)if s[1:]else u`.  Note that this is tremendously inefficient: it calculates `f(s[1:])` twice, which means that adding one to the input length will double the runtime.  So its runtime is exponential in the input length--compared to what you have now, which is linear!  On the other hand, it's one byte shorter, so...

Answer (score 5):

## C, 184 bytes

```c
double h(char c){return ((c=='E')+(c=='S')*2+(c=='W')*3);}double d(char*s){double f=h(*s);if(s[1]){double t=f;f=(f+d(s+1)/90)/2;if(((t-f)>1)||((f-t)>1))f+=2;if(f>=4)f-=4;}return f*90;}
```

**Ungolfed**

```c
// a helper function
double direction_(char ch)
{
    if (ch=='N')
        return 0.;
    else if (ch=='E')
        return 90.;
    else if (ch=='S')
        return 180.;
    else
        return 270.;
}

// this is the main function to call
double direction(char* str)
{
    double fAngle = direction_(str[0]);
    if (str[1])
    {
        double tmp = fAngle + direction(str+1);
        if (tmp>=360.)
            tmp-=360.;
        tmp/=2;

        if (((tmp-fAngle)>90.) || ((tmp-fAngle)<-90.))
        { //  check if we need to take the "other side"; if the resulting angle is more than 90 degrees away, we took the wrong on
            if (tmp>=180.)
                tmp-=180.;
            else
                tmp+=180.;
        }
        fAngle = tmp;
    }
    return fAngle;
}
```

Comment: seems that using float, doesn't give you the precision needed.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :D

Comment: Won't the names of the functions conflict with each other (since the names are both `d`)?

Comment: @qwerp, different signature (one takes char*, other takes only char)

Comment: So C++ automatically chooses the correct one based on the argument? Huh, TIL. Also, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: yes Qwerp, the strong typing in C (and C++) means that the type in the argument list, make it a part of the function signature.

Comment: I think you can save 14 bytes with dividing everything by 90; maybe more if that can give you a different approach on the helper function.

Comment: @titus my golfed helper function has the 90 degrees factored out.  now if I were to factor out the 90 degrees from the main function, I'll need to warp it by another function that will multiply the result by 90 degrees.  not sure that will save 14 bytes

Comment: saves 6 bytes by doing it this way (multiplying by 90 before the return, and dividing by it after the recursive call).

Comment: Function names are not name mangled in C, as they are in C++, so you need to rename one of them if you want it to be C.

Comment: changed the helper function to h

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, <strike>133</strike> 113 bytes

Just improving on @L3viathan's answer because I just made this account and therefore can't make comments yet.

```
d={"N":0,"E":.5,"S":1,"W":1.5}
def B(s):
 b=d[s[-1]]
 for c in s[::-1]:b=(b+d[c])/2+(abs(b-d[c])>1)
 return b*180
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, and nice improvement...

Comment: I didn't see your answer, but Titus had a similar idea, plus I had another, I'm down to 98 now :)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>48</del> <del>42</del> <del>37</del> 32 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to Emigna.
Saved 5 bytes thanks to Titus' idea to work on range [0,4[ and multiply by 90 at the end.
Saved 5 bytes thanks to Adnan's mastery of ancient xor/modulo metamorphosis.

So every angle is reduced from range [0,360[ to range [0,4[ throughout the execution. Result is then multiplied by 90 and displayed.

```
Ç30^5%R¬U¦vXy+;DX-Ä0›2*+4%U}X90*

It can be divided into two sequentially called subprograms.
First program: convert input string into an array of the corresponding angles in range [0,4[
Ç      Take the ascii value of all input characters
 30^5% Dark ascii manipulation that yields [0,1,2,3] for [N,E,S,W]

Now we have an array of integers in range [0,4[.

Second program: actually compute the final angle
R                          Reverse the array
 ¬                         Take the first value (the last of the non-reversed array)
  U                        Pop it from the stack and set X to the same value
   ¦                       Strip the first element
    v                      For each remaining element
     Xy+;                  Compute the average value between the leftmost value and X
         DX-Ä0›            Push 1 if angular distance cast to integer is > 0 (i.e. if it is >= 1), 0 otherwise. It's equivalent to checking >= 90 degrees
               2*+         Multiply by 2 (=2 if angular distance is >= 1 and 0 otherwise) and add it to the formerly computed average value. It's equivalent to multiplying by 180
                  4%       Perform mod 4. It's equivalent to performing mod 360
                    U      Store the result back to X
                     }     End for, mandatory if input has only one character
                      X90* Push X*90 and implicitly display it
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4czMF41JVLCrFXCpnZYeSs7RFgtw4Qw4oC6MiorNCVVfVg5MCo&input=TkVTV05FU1dORVNXTkVTV05FU1dORVNXTkVTV05FU1dORVNXTkVTV05FU1dORVNXTkVTVw)

Potential axes of golfing:

- Not sure if that mod 4 is required (it would save 2 bytes). All test cases work without it, but maybe there exists a tricky case. A mathematical proof to either validate it or nullify it would be top-notch.
- There is no implicit stuff besides displaying the result (closing quote marks, closing brackets).

Comment: Doesn't seem to give the requested result on the `NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE` and `SNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE` test cases.

Comment: Also, there are at least 6 bytes to save in your solution, but I don't know if there is much point in doing it before it's fixed.

Comment: I get respectively 1.0728836059570312e-05 and 90.00000536441803, which are the requested results if I'm not wrong. OP said that scientific notation was fine.

Comment: Weird. Now I do as well. I must have pasted wrong or something, sorry. You can shorten the code down to `v"NESW"yk90*})R¬U¦vXy+;DX-Ä89›180*+360%U}X`.

Comment: Seems I had an extra space at the end of the test cases :)

Comment: Ok I thought something went wrong. Thanks for the golfing!
I actually found out about `89›`, but is it a bug or a feature? I initially started with `90›` but it took some time to realize where the error did come from.

Edit: Wow, surprisingly never used U/X before, nor V/Y.
Also do you have any insight about the mod 360 being mandatory or not?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by bug or feature. You had `90‹_` meaning *not lesser than 90* which is the same as `89›` meaning *greater than 89*. I haven't looked into the math behind it so I'm afraid I can't answer about *360*.

Comment: Actually i had this problem when trying to understand why the following test case wasn't right: `NESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESW`. Here you can see a minimal example, where the absolute value of the diff and the comparison >90 are displayed.
I get false with 90.3515625 > 90
http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=diJORVNXInlrOTAqfSnCpMKpXFvCqERnXyPCpMKuKztEwq4tw4Q9OTDigLo9MTgwKiszNjAlwqlzXVw&input=V05FU1dORVNX

Comment: Oh I deduce from the code that both operands are evaluated as integers before the comparison, so it's more like a feature than a bug. However it is still disturbing if you don't know that ^^ . A better example would be `3;1›`. It is supposed to evaluate 1.5>1 and yields a falsy value.

Comment: Ah yes, now I follow what you mean. There are indeed a bunch of quirks/features in the language that aren't obvious until you actually run into them :)

Comment: Great explanation! It might be worth including a note that `89›` actually means the integer part is greater than 89, which is equivalent to saying the complete number is greater than *or equal to* 90 (which still works fine because exactly 90 should never occur). Currently the comment in the explained code makes it sound like it's checking for greater than 89, whereas your code passes the test cases so is clearly correctly checking for greater than 90.

Comment: I edited the explanation so, however I wrote "cast to integer" since I'm not sure how the operator `›` should behave towards negative floating point values. There is no problem here since it works on the absolute value, but I prefer not making too strong assumptions on the operator.

Comment: You can replace `v"NESW"yk})` with `Ç30^5%` :)

Comment: That's a hell of a hack. I like it!

Comment: I found other ways to do it using ascii codes, but they were 7 bytes long. Nice trick :) .

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>55</s> <s>45</s> 38 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

#### Solution

Requires `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many systems. Asks for direction.

```apl
360|÷○÷180×12○(+÷(|+))/¯12○○2÷⍨'NES'⍳⍞
```

#### Explanation

Goes around the problem by converting each letter to a complex number 1∠*θ* ⇔ *a* + *b · i*, then doing a sum reduction from right-to-left (APL's forte) while normalizing at each step. The final *θ* is then converted to degrees and normalized to be within [0, 360):

`'NES'⍳⍞` the indices of each input letter in "NES"; N→0, E→1, S→2, anything else→3

`○2÷⍨` convert to angles in radians; *θ* = *π* · <sup>***x***</sup>∕<sub>2</sub>

`¯12○` convert to complex numbers on the unit circle; *e<sup>i · θ</sup>*

`(`...`)/` reduce the list with... (i.e. insert the function between the elements of...)

`+÷(|+)` ... the normalized sum; <sup>***x***<sub>*n* - 1</sub> + ***x***<sub>n</sub></sup>∕<sub>|***x***<sub>*n* - 1</sub> + ***x***<sub>n</sub>|</sub>

`12○` convert to angle; *θ*

`÷○÷180×` convert to degrees; <sup>1</sup>∕<sub>*π* · <sup>1</sup>∕<sub>180 · ***x***</sub></sub>

`360|` division remainder when divided by 360

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%7B360%7C%F7%u25CB%F7180%D712%u25CB%28+%F7%28%7C+%29%29/%AF12%u25CB%u25CB2%F7%u2368%27NES%27%u2373%u2375%7D%A8%27WNE%27%20%27WEN%27%20%27WEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEWEN%27%20%27NESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESWNESW%27%20%27NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE%27%20%27NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNW%27%20%27SNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNE%27%20%27SNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNW%27&run)

#### Anecdote

If input and output was as orthogonal complex units, the entire solution would be just:

```apl
(+÷(|+))/
```

The rest of the code is parsing input and formatting output.

Comment: I notice the test outputs do not match those in the challenge to 5 decimal places, making this invalid. Does Dyalog APL have the option of using double precision?

Comment: @trichoplax Yes, `⎕FR←1287` makes use of 128 bit floats, but TryAPL doesn't allow it.

Comment: I think anything greater than or equal to 64 bit floats should work (I've only tested in Python though). Does this mean you can make the code valid but it will then only work for people who have installed the language? Maybe you could show the full valid code for the score, and include the online version that doesn't quite have the required accuracy so people can see that the algorithm is correct.

Comment: @trichoplax Actually, TryAPL uses double precision, but your test cases accumulate errors beyond 53 bits.

Comment: If it can be shown that the difference is due to differences in interpretation of the IEEE 754 standard, that are still standard compliant, then I'll adjust the test cases to make sure both interpretations give the same result to 5 decimal places. I chose the test cases such that they gave the same result to 5 decimal places in Python for both float (double precision) and arbitrary precision decimals. I'll have a look into it.

Comment: I'm still reading up on this, but just thought I'd check: do the slightly different results only happen with TryAPL  online? Do you get the same outputs locally or do they match the test case outputs when it's not online?

Comment: @trichoplax TryAPL is just a web frontend to an actual Dyalog APL running on a virtual Linux on one of our office servers. However, when I compare the TryAPL printed results with my local results (on Windows), I get a difference of `0 0 0 ¯0.00002146121247 5.082197684E¯21 0 0 0`

Comment: Ah I see. So a slight difference but still not matching the test case outputs. This is clearly close enough that it isn't single precision, so I'll do a bit more reading and then probably tweak the test cases. At least I have your online implementation to test my new test cases with...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48568/discussion-between-adam-and-trichoplax).

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I've [replied in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48568/discussion-between-adam-and-trichoplax).

Answer (score 3):

### R, <strike>172</strike> 146 bytes

```
z=rev((0:3*90)[match(scan(,""),c("N","E","S","W"))]);p=z[1];l=length(z);for(i in 2:l)p=(p+z[i])/2+(abs(p-z[i])>180)*180;if(l<2)p=z;sprintf("%f",p)
```

**Ungolfed**

```
z=rev((0:3*90)[match(scan,""),c("N","E","S","W"))]); #1
p=z[1];                                              #2
l=length(z)                                          #3
for(i in 2:l)p=(p+z[i])/2+(abs(p-z[i])>180)*180;     #4
if(l<2)p=z                                           #5
sprintf("%f",p)                                      #6
```

**Explained**

1. Read input from stdin

   - Match input by index to `c("N","E","S","W")`
   - From matched indices: match to the vector of degrees `0:3*90` (instead of `c(0,90,180,270)`)
   - Reverse and store as `z`
2. Initialize `p` to the degree equivalent to last char in input
3. Store length of input as `l`
4. Iteratively, calculate the closest of the two possible bisecting bearings.
5. If only one input is given, set `p` to `z`
6. Format and print

[Try the test cases on R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=We13B66f&version=1)
(note that this is a function due to `scan` not working on R-fiddle)

Comment: Provided that the output is correct to 5 decimal places, you don't need to perform the rounding. From the challenge: `Outputs 0.00001 and 0.000005 are both correct.` So you should be able to save some bytes by not rounding

Comment: @trichoplax I understand. Can the input also be a vector of string characters like. `c("N","N","E")` instead of `"NNE"`? This equivalent to a non-nested python list `["N","N","E"]`.

Comment: Yes. I intended "sequence" to be a general term to include things like arrays, vectors, lists, tuples.

Comment: I think you can save 4 bytes if you divide everything by 90 and printf(p*90).

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>109 105</s> 103 bytes

```
h=180
a#b|abs(a-b)<h=n|n>h=n-h|1>0=n+h where n=(a+b)/2 -- calculates the new "mean" on the cirlce
f 'N'=0                                          -- translates characters to angles
f 'E'=90
f 'S'=h
f _=270
foldr1(#).map f                                  -- traverses the whole string
```

Thanks for -2 byte @xnor!

Comment: The exhaustive list for `f` looks long, but I'm having trouble finding anything shorter. Closest I got was `f c=90*until(\i->"NESW"!!i==c)(+1)0` (35). I think you can replace `'W'` with `_`.

Comment: Yeah I also expected there to be something shorter, but didn't find anything. Thanks for the `_`!

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>347</s> 327 bytes

*Thanks to @Titus for taking off a few*

This can probably be golfed more, but at least it works (I think):

```
(defun d(c)(if(eql c #\N)0(if(eql c #\E)1(if(eql c #\S)2(if(eql c #\W)3)))))(defun m(a b)(if(> a b)(rotatef a b))(if(<(+(- 4 b)a)(- b a))(+(/(+(- 4 b)a)2)b)(+(/(- b a)2)a)))(defun f(s)(let((c))(setf c(d(char s(1-(length s)))))(do((a)(p(-(length s)2)(1- p)))((< p 0))(setf a(char s p))(setf c(m(d a)c)))(format t"~5$"(* c 90))))
```

Usage:

```
* (f "WNE")
337.50000
NIL
```

Function `d` takes a character `N`, `E`, `W`, or `S` and returns the appropriate degree. Function `m` gets the approprate combined degree of two given directions. Function `f` iterates through the provided string, computes the appropriate degree, and prints it as a floating point.

Comment: My LISP is rusty, but can dividing everything by 90 save 6 bytes?

Comment: @Titus I think it would. I've realized some other improvements so I'll add this when I'm at my computer

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, <del>183</del> <del>181</del> 175 bytes

```
>~#+:#25#%6*#/`#2_$>5%4*:00p"Z}"4*:***20g#v_+2/00g10g-:8`\0\-8`+!v
v5:+*:*:"d"/+55+5$_^#!:\p01/**:*4"}Z":p020<%**:*"(2Z"+**5*:*"0}"!<
>5>+#<%#56#58#:*#/+\#5:#5_$$$,,,".">:#,_@
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Pn4jKzojMjUjJTYqIy9gIzJfJD41JTQqOjAwcCJafSI0KjoqKioyMGcjdl8rMi8wMGcxMGctOjhgXDBcLThgKyF2CnY1OisqOio6ImQiLys1NSs1JF9eIyE6XHAwMS8qKjoqNCJ9WiI6cDAyMDwlKio6KiIoMloiKyoqNSo6KiIwfSIhPAo-NT4rIzwlIzU2IzU4IzoqIy8rXCM1OiM1XyQkJCwsLCIuIj46IyxfQA&input=U05OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OVw)

**Explanation**

This follows a similar algorithm to many of the other answers, only it's using fixed point calculations emulated with integers since Befunge doesn't support floating point.

Thanks to [@Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) for the ASCII-to-int routine.

```
 ~ : 5 6* ` _$        while ((c = getchar()) > 30)  // ends with any ctrl char or EOF
> + 2 %6 / 2            push(c / 2 % 6 + 2)         // partial conversion to int

                      do {
  5%                    dir = pop() % 5             // completes the conversion to int   
  4*:00p                dir *= 4; lowres_dir = dir  // used by the 180-flip calculation
  "Z}"4*:***            dir *= 22500000             // this is 90000000 / 4 
  20g_                  if (!first_pass) {
    +2/                   dir = (dir+last_dir)/2    // last_dir is second item on stack
    00g10g-               diff = lowres_dir - last_lowres_dir
    :8`\0\-8`+!!          flip = diff>8 || -diff>8
    "}0"*:*5**+           dir += flip * 180000000   // add 180 degrees if we need to flip
    "Z2("*:**%            dir %= 360000000          // keep within the 360 degree range
                        }
  020p                  first_pass = false
  :"Z}"4*:**/10p        last_lowres_dir = dir / 22500000
  \                     last_dir = dir              // saved as second item on stack
  :!_                 } while (!stack.empty())

$                     pop()                         // this leaves the final dir on top
5+55+/                dir = (dir + 5)/10            // round down to 5 decimal places
"d":*:*+              dir += 100000000              // add a terminating digit
                      while (true) {                // convert into chars on stack
:55 + % 6 8 * +\ : _    push(dir%10+'0'); if (!dir) break
   > < 5 5 : /+ 5 5     dir /= 10
                      }

$$$                   pop() x 3                     // drop the chars we don't need
,,,                   putchar(pop()) x 3            // output first three chars
"."                   push('.')                     // add a decimal point
>:#,_@                while(c=pop()) putchar(c)     // output the remaining chars
```

Comment: Does that just mean you need to emulate a larger fixed point type (more decimal places)? The test cases are designed to require double precision, which is no more than 17 significant figures (a maximum of 16 decimal places), and 14 decimal places might possibly be enough.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```apl
90×(4|2÷⍨+-4×2<∘|-)/'NES'⍳⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY89TwJBEIZ7fsV1q9HD/ZqdXWNLS0NBfYGcIV48c1xjgM4ofhyxMdhYaGVvCAmJFf9k/8g552FiAcxmMjuZ99l3J7pKwv51lKTnYS@JhsNBr/Szl0Hqb595w0/v4tLx9fxAj@V66YvPo1Cv5/LMT1/H4eEJa7c6zBdfRJSkLWOifDET/umbTUbsmNGgyoxEC@YfPmiypL6XsZgFvngL8izqx5dBngZUGjnxI5L6@/eMrrEvVqcsvWD@8YbF0SChZ1Y0ziYN1m23WB4ohU2gptX@32w7tYA3eRUoQAKgQsW1sUgQLdLdlURa13S/oaTTGlEbicYC/NHbo/ph7Sg4SmuV4eAAuRJyN1TZKaj9rJMohFFOcy1d7dXZY@Y2@4EyWgvLpUMLAozcw1V@0mz200YBWOGQS6GtVgg/)